# Can I retrain the spells I pick with Greater Crossblooded Evolution during downtime?

Tags: feats, pathfinder-2e, sorcerer, downtime

Pretty straightforward question--does [GCBE](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=629) give a Sorcerer the ability to retrain and learn any two spells during downtime?

If so, how long does it take?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Yes, you can

Crossblooded Evolution says:

> You can have one spell in your spell repertoire from a tradition other than the one that matches your bloodline. You cast that spell as a spell from your bloodline’s tradition. **You can swap which spell you add and from which tradition as you could any other sorcerer spell**

So for plain Crossblooded Evolution, you can swap the spell during downtime, as the Spell Repertoire rule of the sorcerer says:

> You can also swap out spells by retraining during downtime.

The Greater Crossblooded Evolution has Crossblooded Evolution as a prerequisite, and refers back to it when it says:

> You can have up to three spells from other traditions in your spell repertoire, **rather than just one**.

So I think it's fair to assume that these three spells follow the same rules as the one spell, and you can retrain them during downtime.

The downtime entry says:

> Downtime mode is played day-by-day rather than minute-by-minute or scene-by-scene. Usually this mode of play occurs when you are in the safety of a settlement, maybe recovering from your adventures or studying an artifact you found.

and the Core Rulebook (thanks to @Brandon for this piece of info) was updated to include

> You can change a class feature that required a choice, making a different choice instead. **Some, like changing a spell in your spell repertoire, take a week**.

So making that change will cost you a week of of downtime.